# How to sort Oracle tables by their modified time

Tags: oracle

I am very new to oracle and I need to sort tables by their last modified time. It is called DML I guess but I am not sure about it. Sorry, if this is asked before or impossible to do.

**Edit:**
I am trying to fetch some data from a discontinued application. But there are more than 600 tables in this database. The application still use this database. So if I make some changes in the application. For example, I can give some permission to a user. Then I will run the SQL I am looking for and see one table that is modified (the data inside) on top of result. So I will understand which table holds which data. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for DML modifications:

```
select * from SYS.ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS where TABLE_OWNER = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME' order by TIMESTAMP;
```

If you're looking for DDL modifications:

```
select * from SYS.ALL_OBJECTS where OWNER = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME' and OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' order by LAST_DDL_TIME;
```

If you just want to sort data from a table:

```
select * from YOUR_TABLE order by COLUMN_NAME; -- or multiple column names
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain what you really mean?

What is "sort tables"? You sort data in tables, not tables themselves, unless you're querying (e.g.) USER_OBJECTS and want to sort tables in your schema by LAST_DDL_TIME (it is time when that table was last *modified* (altered). For example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select object_name, last_ddl_time
  2  from user_objects
  3  where object_type = 'TABLE'
  4  order by last_ddl_time;

OBJECT_NAME                    LAST_DDL_TIME
------------------------------ -------------------
SALGRADE                       19.04.2018 08:15:27
DEPT                           10.12.2018 08:58:24
EMP                            10.12.2018 08:58:25
BONUS                          17.12.2018 07:11:10
EMPLOYEES                      20.12.2018 08:32:22
```

If it is about sorting rows in a table, then:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, hiredate
  2  from emp
  3  order by hiredate;

     EMPNO ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ---------- -------------------
      7369 SMITH      17.12.1980 00:00:00
      7499 ALLEN      20.02.1981 00:00:00
      7521 WARD       22.02.1981 00:00:00
      7566 JONES      02.04.1981 00:00:00
```

If it is something else, what is it?

Comment: Huh, right. It isn't a simple task. You should query metadata for all DATE datatype columns and check all of them for - for example - today's date. It can be done, but I guess that it would be simpler if you have access to source code. For example, it if was Oracle Forms, open the .fmb file and check what table is that data block based on. It would answer your question (i.e. you'd know which table gets updated).